# Android HashMap - What Does This Code Do?

Tags: android

```
const-string v1, "12345678"

const-string v2, "George#1"

invoke-virtual {v0, v1, v2}, Ljava/util/HashMap;->put(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

and

```
const-string v1, "12345678"

const-string v2, "12345678 transaction"

invoke-virtual {v0, v1, v2}, Ljava/util/HashMap;->put(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

Sorry for the very newbie question but was wondering what these pieces of code do?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v0 v1 v2 are the register address in the Dalvik Virtual Machine.

```
const-string v1, "12345678"
```

creates a String "12345678" and save it to the register v1.

```
invoke-virtual {v0, v1, v2}
```

calls the method put(..) and it takes three parameters v0 is 'this', v1 is "12345678" and v2 is "George#1"